# How to listen to server events in ng2-signal r

Tags: angular

I have followed the instructions on ng2-signalr and this is what I have come up with:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { SignalRModule } from 'ng2-signalr';
import { SignalRConfiguration } from 'ng2-signalr';

export function createConfig(): SignalRConfiguration {
  const config = new SignalRConfiguration();
  config.hubName = 'MyHub';
  config.qs = { user: 'donald' };
  config.url = 'http://localhost:8089/';
  config.executeEventsInZone = true; // optional, default is true
  config.executeErrorsInZone = false; // optional, default is false
  config.executeStatusChangeInZone = true; // optional, default is true
  return config;
}
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SignalRModule.forRoot(createConfig)
  ],
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicesService } from 'src/services.service';
import '../../node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.js';
import { SignalR, 
    BroadcastEventListener, 
    IConnectionOptions, 
    SignalRConnection } from 'ng2-signalr';

declare var $:any;
// import 'expose-loader?jQuery!jquery';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  title = 'client';

  options: IConnectionOptions = { hubName: 'MyHub' };

  onMessageSent$ = new BroadcastEventListener<string>('heartbeat')

  public _connection: SignalRConnection

  nick = '';
  message = '';
  messages: string[] = [];
  

  constructor(
    private ser: ServicesService,
    private _signalR: SignalR,
  ){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this._signalR.connect(this.options);
    

    this._signalR.connect().then((c) => {
      console.log(c);
    });
    
    this._connection.listen(this.onMessageSent$);
    this.onMessageSent$.subscribe((chatMessage: string) => {
      console.log(chatMessage);
    });
  }
}
```

It can connect fine to the Signalr server. But in my console I get this error:

[image]

And I can't obtain console log out the data from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to subscribe to "connect"

```
public _connection: SignalRConnection
nick = '';
message = '';
messages: string[] = [];
private signalRSubscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
configuration: any = {
  // your config object here
};

constructor(
  private ser: ServicesService,
  private _signalR: SignalR,
){}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.connect();
}

connect(): void {
 this._signalR.connect(this.configuration).then((c) => {
 this._connection = c;
 c.listen(this.onMessageSent$);
 this.signalRSubscriptions.push(onMessageSent$.subscribe((chatMessage: string) => {
 console.log(chatMessage);
 }));
 }).catch((error) => {
   // this.reconnect();
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning anything to the `this._connection`. After quick walk through readme on ng2-singalr on github I belive you need to do following:

```
 public _connection: SignalRConnection

  nick = '';
  message = '';
  messages: string[] = [];


  constructor(
    private ser: ServicesService,
    private _signalR: SignalR,
  ){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._connection = this._signalR.connect()

    this._connection.listen(this.onMessageSent$);
    this.onMessageSent$.subscribe((chatMessage: string) => {
      console.log(chatMessage);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is still a no go.

Comment: Can you reproduce error on stacblitz ? Or at least tell me what error you have after using my solution ?